# Display an icon only for certain input values in Squib

Tags: ruby, svg, squib

My card game (built with [Squib](https://github.com/andymeneely/squib)) is based on a CSV file. In this file I have (among others) one column called `main`.

Here's the content of the column... as you see, a lot of `nil`:

```
print data['main']
> [3, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, 0, 0, nil, nil, 0, nil, nil, nil, 0, nil, nil, 0, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, 1, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, -1, nil, nil, nil, nil, 0, 0, 0, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil]
```

**Desired behavior**

For each card (row):

- If there is a value in this column, I would like to display the value, with a SVG as a background
- If there is no value (`nil`), I would like to skip the text and the svg alltogether

**What I tried**

1 - I tried the following, but `data['sprint']` is an `array` not a `value`, so the `==` does not work:

```
data = Squib.csv file: 'data.csv'
[...]
if data['Sprint'] != nil
    text str: data['Sprint3'], layout: 'sprint3'
    svg layout: 'block', file: 'svg\left_block.svg'     
end
```

2 - So I attempted to iterate through the array with an `each` method, but this of course leads to displaying every element of the array on each card:

```
data['Main'].each do |n|
    if n != nil
        text str: n, layout: 'main'
        svg layout: 'block', file: 'svg\up_block.svg'   
    end
end
```

My Ruby knowledge is here at its end. I have no idea how to display one element only when the value in the `main` column is not `nil`. Any idea? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Squib's svg works the way you want it to - if it gets nil for file it won't do anything. So in your layout file just put:

```
block:
  file: 'svg\up_block.svg'
```

And then the svg call does NOT have that "file" option (that sets it for all cards no matter what)

When layout is nil, it'll default to the svg method's "file", which is nil, which happens to do nothing - that's what you want. So then your data field could be something like ['block', nil, nil, nil] and would only show up on the first card.

Check out some new articles I've written on the topic: 
http://squib.readthedocs.org/en/latest/arrays.html
http://squib.readthedocs.org/en/latest/guides/getting-started/part_2_iconography.html

(work in progress, of course)

Also, these can also be helpful: https://github.com/andymeneely/squib/blob/master/samples/ranges.rb

That if-statement reminds me how nanDeck would do it - not the same way that Squib works. You COULD do it with an "each", or a "select", but that's more complicated than it needs to be.

(full disclosure: I am the developer of Squib)

Comment: Thanks for your answer Andy, I was thinking I overcomplicated that one myself. So no need for conditional logic, that's good :D but I'm still unsure how to make it work though. Do I apply this `block` layout to a naked `svg` call => `svg layout: 'block'`? This is not going to react to the data coming in, is it? If not, do I apply it to the `text` call like this => `text str: data['Main'], layout: 'block'`? This unfortunately doesn't work on my end yet, the svg is not displayed in this case...

Comment: I think finally understood what you meant: you meant to set the layout as part of the input data, e.g. a layout column. Thus using a call like `svg layout: data['layout']`I get an array and only the non `nil` values will then be taken into account. If this assumption is correct, I "just" need to find out how to create this layout column without having to repeat myself too much in the CSV file (if a value is present in column A, then put layout 'block' in column B, leave empty otherwise...)

Comment: Yeah, that's what I meant. And of course you don't have to call it `layout` - call it something descriptive from your game, like `svg layout: data['faction']`. And yep, your assumption is correct - think of it like categorizing your cards and styling them according to the category.